# How to list all tables which references a certain row of another table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently working with a project that needs to clear some unused fields and normalize tables on its database in order to make it look better. 
One of these tables has a field that is not a foreign key (but it should), so I can't use *sp_help* in order to know what tables are related.

[image]

My current task is to delete the rows with **IdTipoEspecialidad = 3** only if there isn't any table that uses this rows (because I need to delete both).

Is there some shortcut or query that makes this task easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all these non-foreign-keyed columns at least follow some naming convention, you can execute the following query:

```
SELECT
    'SELECT * FROM [' + schemas.name + '].[' + tables.name + ']' 
        + ' WHERE [' + columns.name + '] = 3'
FROM
    sys.schemas
    INNER JOIN sys.tables
        ON schemas.schema_id = tables.schema_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns
        ON tables.object_id = columns.object_id
WHERE
    columns.name LIKE '%IdTipoEspecialidad%'
```

The output of that query will give you a bunch of other queries, which you can run to see if there is any column referencing that specific row.

Comment: EXCELLENT ANSWER! Thanks, it will help me a lot. With the first two queries I found all tables which were using this certain id.